# How we can run codeigniter 4 in local host or subdirectory without changing apache host configuration file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to run CodeIgniter 4 localhost using a subfolder like http://localhost/codeigniter4login/ but the root URL always shows http://localhost we need http://localhost/codeigniter4login/.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In public/ directory, copy index.php and .htaccess to your root project directory.

Step 2: In the root project directory, open index.php and edit the following line:

Change on Index.php:

$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php'; **change to** ($pathsPath = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve these. One by editing the App.php config file other by the .evn file.

Follow the steps:

**Option 1**

1. Open file "app/Config/App.php"
2. Find **public $baseUR** and change value to **http://localhost/codeigniter4login/**.
3. Save the file.

**Option 2** (Using Env)

1. Open file ".evn"
2. Find **app.baseURL** and add the value  **http://localhost/codeigniter4login/** to it
3. Save the file.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what is happening?

Comment: public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/codeigniter4login/';
I have updated base URL but in application i am geting localhost as root URL it should be http://localhost/codeigniter4login/. REF : http://prntscr.com/110pujn

Answer (score 0):

To configure your localhost to achieve this: The root `.htaccess` file contains a line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Assuming you've set your `BaseUrl` in the `.env` file as others have suggested you need to add your subfolder to that line and you should hopefully be set.